# VBA Excel: Search in folders and subsolders specific extension, and write in excel the title

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a VBA code to search in folders an subfolders file extension('.csv'), and write the file title in excel workbook.

Comment: You need an qualified employee, stackoverlow is not a free coding service please read : [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and I got this working:

```
Sub foo()
Dim iFilesNum As Integer
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim recMyFiles() As FoundFileInfo
Dim blFilesFound As Boolean


Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For xy = 2 To LastRow

blFilesFound = FindFiles(Sheet1.Cells(xy, 1).Value, recMyFiles, iFilesNum, "*.csv", True) 'where column 1 on Sheet1 contains the Paths to be searched, include more rows with more paths to search through them too
If blFilesFound Then
    For iCount = 1 To iFilesNum
        With recMyFiles(iCount)
            Sheet2.Cells(iCount, 1).Value = .sPath & .sName 'place the results in Sheet2
        End With
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "No file(s) found matching the specified file spec.", vbInformation, "File(s) not Found"
End If

Next xy
MsgBox iFilesNum
End Sub
```

And then in a module add the following:

```
Type FoundFileInfo
    sPath As String
    sName As String
End Type

Function FindFiles(ByVal sPath As String, _
    ByRef recFoundFiles() As FoundFileInfo, _
    ByRef iFilesFound As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    Optional ByVal blIncludeSubFolders As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    Dim iCount As Integer           '* Multipurpose counter
    Dim sFileName As String         '* Found file name
    '*
    '* FileSystem objects
    Dim oFileSystem As Object, _
        oParentFolder As Object, _
        oFolder As Object, _
        oFile As Object

    Set oFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oParentFolder = oFileSystem.GetFolder(sPath)
    If oParentFolder Is Nothing Then
        FindFiles = False
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set oParentFolder = Nothing
        Set oFileSystem = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    sPath = IIf(Right(sPath, 1) = "\", sPath, sPath & "\")
    '*
    '* Find files
    sFileName = Dir(sPath & sFileSpec, vbNormal)
    If sFileName <> "" Then
        For Each oFile In oParentFolder.Files
            If LCase(oFile.Name) Like LCase(sFileSpec) Then
                iCount = UBound(recFoundFiles)
                iCount = iCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve recFoundFiles(1 To iCount)
                With recFoundFiles(iCount)
                    .sPath = sPath
                    .sName = oFile.Name
                End With
            End If
        Next oFile
        Set oFile = Nothing         '* Although it is nothing
    End If
    If blIncludeSubFolders Then
        '*
        '* Select next sub-forbers
        For Each oFolder In oParentFolder.SubFolders
            FindFiles oFolder.Path, recFoundFiles, iFilesFound, sFileSpec, blIncludeSubFolders
        Next
    End If
    FindFiles = UBound(recFoundFiles) > 0
    iFilesFound = UBound(recFoundFiles)
    On Error GoTo 0
    '*
    '* Clean-up
    Set oFolder = Nothing           '* Although it is nothing
    Set oParentFolder = Nothing
    Set oFileSystem = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: @V. MCR please could you mark my response as an asnwer if it has helped you? Thank you.